Do we need @types/* when we are not using TypeScript?
When scaffolding a React project using Vite like,
pnpm create vite my-react-app --template react

Any idea why @types/react and @types/react-dom are added in package.json when the project is not using TypeScript?
"devDependencies": {
  "@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
  "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
  "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.2",
  "eslint": "^9.11.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.12",
  "globals": "^15.9.0",
  "vite": "^5.4.8"
}


Type information is used by many text editors to provide capabilities unrelated to type-checking — e.g. code completion.

Short answer is: no. You don't need those dependencies to run your project.
Even if you keep them it will add extra benefit and will not add any additional code in your production bundle.
While you may not need these dependencies directly in your code, they help maintain compatibility across tools in the JavaScript ecosystem that rely on TypeScript types for better developer support​ in IDE/Code Editors.
reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html
